# remove html characters in blackberry java

Tags: blackberry

how to remove html characters in a webservice in blackberry java ?
(ie remove "$" withString "%24" and "&" withString "%26" and so on..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s="http://199.199.199.199/webservices/login.php";
int b = (int)s.charAt(i++);
if ((b>=0x30 && b<=0x39) || (b>=0x41 && b<=0x5A) || (b>=0x61 && b<=0x7A)) {
tmp.append((char)b);
}
else {
tmp.append("%");
if (b <= 0xf) tmp.append("0");
tmp.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
}
Dialog.alert(tmp.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use one of the many freely-available URL encoders. Search for "blackberry url encoder" or "java me url encoder" or something similar. For example, [here's one](http://weblog.cenriqueortiz.com/java-me-midp-articles-tech-tips-source-code/tech-tip-simple-url-encoder/) and [here's another](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/URL-Encoding-and-Decoding/m-p/137165#M15627).

It's always been a mystery to me why URL encoding and decoding was not included in either MIDP or the BlackBerry API given that it's so useful.